# "He became, as the Guinness Book of World Records called him" - is it okay to repeat the pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, style

Is **"him"** required in the following sentence? Little confused.

> He became, as the Guinness Book of World Records called **him**, "the most
>   perfectly developed man in the history of the world."

Comment: Why do you think it's **not** OK?

Answer (score 5):

It's entirely okay, grammatically, to repeat the pronoun there, and in fact given the rest of the sentence it's **required**: the only way to avoid he+him is to rephrase to avoid "called". [CopperKettle has given some good alternatives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/61868/10820), although I don't think rephrasing is necessary in this case; there's little awkwardness when repeating pronouns, especially if it's not exactly the same one.

Answer (score 3):

> **He** became, as the Guinness Book of World Records called **him**, "the most perfectly developed man in the history of the world."

If you suspect that the repetition of the pronoun is jarring a bit, you might remodel the sentence slightly:

> He became, **in the words used** by the Guinnes Book of World Records, "the most perfectly developed man in the history of the world."

or:

> He became, **according to** the Guinnes Book of World Records, "the most perfectly developed man in the history of the world."

Alternatively, to keep most of the original sentence intact

> "He became, as the Guiness Book of World Records **put it**, "the most perfectly developed man in the history of the world." (all kudos to [Au101](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/19786/au101))

Comment: +1. Alternatively, to keep most of the original sentence intact, "He became, as the Guiness Book of World Records **put it**, ..."

Comment: @Au101 - thank you! I've borrowed your formulation, for the sake of enlightenment.. and points, of course! (0:

Comment: Thank you so much @CopperKettle for the help. Quite interesting explanation. Is it okay if I keep the sentence same **called him**?

Comment: @Au101 I find **put it** is great. Thank you. Appreciate. Is it okay if I keep the sentence same **called him**?

Comment: @Roy - I'm not a native speaker, so I'm not sure whether it is okay. My guess is that it is technically okay but a bit ackward stylistically. Wait for a native speaker's opinion! P.S. and we use the definite article before *same*: **the same**.

Comment: *In my opinion* @CopperKettle provides you with a number of nice alternatives that one might *prefer*. But I think your original sentence with "called him" is absolutely fine, even if it may not be the most elegant way possible of expressing this idea. Is it okay to repeat the pronoun? Yes, absolutely. I see no problem here - certainly not in the general case. Although it's possible that this *specific* sentence could be rewritten in a nicer way.

Comment: Is "him" required in the following sentence? You certainly couldn't have 'He became, as the Guinness Book of World Records called, "the most perfectly developed man in the history of the world."'

Comment: @Au101: well, that's grammatical. But what it means is that at the very moment Guinness called, he became "the most perfectly developed man". A far less likely thing to want to say, especially with the snigger quotes there. The real sentence wants to use the transitive verb "called", meaning to use a name or description for something, not the intransitive version (perhaps to do with telephones or visiting a house). That's what "him" is needed for, the transitive version of the verb needs an object.

Comment: @SteveJessop, yeah, I guess so - that possibility didn't even occur to me. In this case, though, it comes to the same thing: you certainly shouldn't omit the second pronoun altogether

Comment: There is a very slight nuance of meaning that isn't carried through to your "according to..." alternative sentence. In the original sentence, the implied meaning is that the speaker holds the same opinion of *him* as does the Guinness Book of World Records. In this alternative sentence, the speaker merely reports what GBWR says, regardless of whether he/she agrees. (And in fact, this structure sometimes indicates some level of *dis*agreement.)

Comment: Thank you everyone, esp. @SteveJessop for a nice conversation.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Thank you so much. I never used this structure. Accidentally, I wrote it write : )